# npm version on Azure Pipelines (VSTS) upon merge

Tags: git, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are holding a `CI` pipeline to run on every PR.
Once a PR marked as completed, it auto merge the code to `master` branch.

We want to update the version in `package.json` using `npm version`, however, we have a branch policy to prevent direct push to `master` branch.

How can we apply the `npm version` command upon the PR completion and make it commit the new version to `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant **Bypass Branch Policies** permissions to a specific user, then he can push the directly to the master:

[image]

The permissions are managed in along with other Git permissions.

Comment: thank you, any thoughts about how to hook this directly on PR completion?

Comment: You can create a new build with only 1 task that commit and push the file (with the user permissions), the last task in the PR build will be trigger the another build.

Comment: You're welcome! if you need help how to trigger another build from current build you can ask :)